# What are some known 2D/3D physics engines for XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, physics-engine

I'm looking for a physics engine to use in an XNA project (2D or 3D). Because it's for XNA, it needs to fulfill some requirements:

1. Not necessarily free, but close to it is obviously preferred
2. Managed code only (or it won't run on the 360)

Answer (score 15):

2D

- [Velcro Physics](https://github.com/Genbox/VelcroPhysics) is based on box2d but has lot of its own improvements and innovations.
- [Box2Dx](http://code.google.com/p/box2dx/) & [Box2D.Xna](https://github.com/n1ckd0r/Box2D.XNA) are both ports of [box 2D](http://www.box2d.org/)
- I think theres a port of chipmunk physics out there, but i cant find the link

3D

- [JigLib](https://github.com/jdarc/jiglibx) one of the earliest 3d physics engines for xna, been used quite a bit
- [Jitter](https://github.com/mattleibow/jitterphysics) Quite a new engine, but more per formant than JigLib
- [Henge3D](https://github.com/bretternst/Henge3D) A newer engine to the scene, impressive multi-threading
- [BEPU physics](https://github.com/bepu/bepuphysics1) has just recently became free for both commercial and non-commerical use.